# Очень длинный тэг ID3v2

Tags: c++, mp3, id3v2

Читаю на с++ id3v2 тэги mp3 файла. В какой-то момент появляется тэг APIC, у которого размер фрейма слишком велик для помещения в память. Программа крашится, как это обойти?
Читаю тэги так в цикле:

```
char input[4];
file.read(input, 4); //название тэга
cout << input << "    ";
delete[] input;
input = new char[4];
file.read(input, 4); //длина тэга
unsigned int length = (int)input[0]*2097152 + (int)input[1]*16384 +  (int)input[2]*128 +  (int)input[0];
delete[] input;
input = new char[2];
file.read(input, 2); //флаги
delete[] input;
input = new char[length]; // здесь ошибка из-за очень большого length (больше размера файла - 4Гб)
file.read(input, length);
cout << input << endl;
```

Ошибка появляется нетолько на APIC, но и на PRIV в другом файле по аналогичной причине.

Comment: Для прочтения заголовка не нужно динамически выделять память. Для чтения длины в том числе можно было просто объявить переменную, и в нее по указателю прочитать 4 байта: `unsigned int length; file.read(&length, 4);` (предполагаем, что int 32-битный, но лучше вообще явно использовать переменную с размером 32 бита (`uint32_t`)). Ну и проверьте на всякий случай, точно ли там находится поле длины, а не что-то другое.

Comment: @insolor спасибо, но как проверить, что там находится именно поле длины? Послать uint32_t* в read не получается - компилятор ругается на инвалидно преобразование к char*.

Comment: еще раз свериться с доками по формату)